# Confused about regular expression code not working

Tags: javascript, regex

```
var regex=/\u00E(0|1)/g;
```

I want to find  `à` or  `á` in the string.
Is this regex correct? Why isnt it working?

Comment: Why don't you try it and see if it works or not? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't work because the Unicode escape sequence `\u` expects four hexadecimal digits after the sequence like this: `\uNNNN` where each `N` is a hexadecimal digit.

Instead use literal characters in the regex like @Jacks soluion, or use @Fabrizio's solution.

Comment: what if the regex was /al(t|l)/g; will this find 'all' or 'alt'?

Answer (score 1):

Use instead

```
var regex= /[\u00E0\u00E1]/g;
```

Answer (score 1):

You're breaking up the Unicode sequence in your expression and an unfinished sequence gets interpreted as a literal `'\\u00E'`.

That said, you can just put those characters in the expression itself:

```
var regex = /[àá]/;

regex.text('állo'); // true
```

Answer (score 0):

Literals need to be explicit. You need

```
var regex=/\u00E0|\u00E1/g;
```

Comment: You have a closing paren with no open.

Comment: That was true for a split second :)

Comment: I was wondering why my code is not working /(\u00E0)|(\u00E1)/g; works

Comment: You don't even need the parenthesis.